# Absolutely positioned play button icon not showing in Firefox

Tags: css, css-position

I have a video gallery section in which two versions, normal and hover, of a play button are absolutely positioned above a preview image of a video. For some reason the play buttons do not show at all in Firefox. The current version of the page is [here](http://staging.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/fitness-videos.html), and the code is as follows:

```
<div class="videoPreview">
    <div class="videoPreviewImg">
        <img src="img/promo/groupFitness.jpg">
        <i class="playButtonHover"></i>
        <i class="playButton"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
div.videoPreview {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 21%;
  margin: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

div.videoPreview:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

div.videoPreviewImg { 
  position: relative;

}

div.videoPreviewImg img {
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.videoPreviewImg i {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-left: -24px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
}

div.videoPreviewImg:hover i.playButton {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Try giving the `div.videoPreview` a height as well.

Comment: What version of Firefox? Just checked on Firefox v22 and it looks ok

Comment: @apaul34208, the version I was using was 21, but I just updated it and the issue is still there. So you saw the gray play button above the images, which transitions to blue on hover?

Comment: @Jean-Paul, I can't give it a set height, because it is responsive. This method, as it was used on the front page (see my reply to your answer below) didn't require that the parent container have a height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.videoPreviewImg { 
  position: relative;
}
```

The 'wrapping' div of your playbuttons is positioned relative while the playbuttons itself are positioned absolute.

Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document flow. They position themselves relative to their parent. If a containing div is positioned relative, then the contained absolutely positioned div will position itself within that parent. HOWEVER, because the absolutely positioned element is removed from the flow, the parent div will collapse because, as far as it is concerned, it does not contain anything.

If the containing div is not positioned, then the absolutely positioned div will use the next level up parent.

So you can change the position:

```
div.videoPreviewImg { 
    position: absolute;
}
```

Or try and set the position of the playbuttons to relative and then adjust their appearance with `margins`.

Also, don't blame FF. You have probably tested it in IE which implies that FF is right, but IE is not.

Good luck!

### UPDATE

Looking at your website in Firefox edition 3.6.28 I found the following:

[image]

Where, as you can see, the first preview button shows perfectly.

I then continued to look at your code, and to my astonishment, I found the following:

```
<div class="videoPreview">

                <a class="video1" href="#">
                    <div class="videoPreviewImg">
                        <img class="actualVideoPreImg" src="img/promo/groupFitness.jpg">
                        <img class="playButtonHover" src="../img/playButtonHover.png">
                        <img class="playButton" src="../img/playButton.png">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="videoPreview">
                <a class="video2" href="#">
                    <div class="videoPreviewImg">
                        <img src="img/promo/mealPlans.jpg">
                        <i class="playButtonHover"></i>
                        <i class="playButton"></i>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>


            <div class="videoPreview">  
                <div class="videoPreviewImg">
                    <img src="img/promo/personalTraining.jpg"/>
                    <i class="playButtonHover"></i>
                    <i class="playButton"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
//etc. etc. etc.
```

If you look closely, you can see that only for the first `img`, the syntax of the playbuttons is correct. For the other videos, the playbuttons are declared as:

```
<i class="playButtonHover"></i>
<i class="playButton"></i>
```

Whereas (of course) they should be

```
<img class="playButtonHover" src="../img/playButtonHover.png">
<img class="playButton" src="../img/playButton.png">
```

Just as for the first video.

So actually, the buttons do appear but without an image.

*This begs the question: then why does it work in Chrome?*

Then I found something very remarkable again:

[image]

As you can see, chrome does not have the correct syntax at all.
So what I think happens is that Chrome has a very smart 'code-fixing' system behind it which 'guesses' the correct syntax if you made a syntax error.

But then again how does chrome know which image to grasp from the server?

Anyway, I think if you fix the `i tags` which are normally only used like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp), then you will be fine.

You can either replace the `i tags` by using a `div` or just replace it (like I mentioned before) with an `img` tag.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jean-Paul, thank you for the input. I actually first tested it in Chrome, where it worked fine. Have yet to test in IE. 

I can't set the position to relative because it will preserve a space below the image where the icons would normally be positioned, plus I will have to use px to move it where I want it, which doesn't fit with the responsive design.

I also tried your suggestion of changing the positioning of the videoPreviewImg div to absolute, but that did not fix the problem either.

Comment: I'm perplexed why it is not working, because I used the same method ont the site's front page (see index page of site linked in post) to get a yellow bar and text positioned above some images. See the following comments for the code.

Comment: `<div class="promoItem"> 
     <img src="img/promo/groupFitness.jpg">
     <div class="colorBG"></div>
     <div class="promoLabel">Group Fitness Classes</div>
    </div>`

Comment: `div.promoItem { 
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 29.333333%;
  margin: 0 2% 20px 2%;
  border: 1px solid #A0A0A0; 
}

div.promoItem img { 
  z-index: 1; 
  max-width: 100%;
}
div.promoItem div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}`

Comment: @BrandonMcPeak: where is the site link?

Comment: @BrandonMcPeak: I can help you, but then you have to show me the site such that I know exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jean-Paul. The link to site page in question is at staging.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/fitness-videos.html. If you look at it in Chrome, you'll see what I'm going for. Thanks again!

Comment: @BrandonMcPeak: Checkout the update. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hey Jean-Paul, you were checking out the site as I was converting the icons from <i> to <img>. That's why you saw the icon showing up properly on the first video gallery item in Firefox. So you were correct, this was the thing to do. Thank you very much for your help and your thorough reply!

Comment: @BrandonMcPeak: glad to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was looking at the main slideshow/video player yesterday...

To fix the other play buttons change:

```
.playButton {
  content: url(../img/playButton.png);
}
.playButtonHover {
  content: url(../img/playButtonHover.png);
}
```

to

```
.playButton {
  background: url(../img/playButton.png);
}
.playButtonHover {
  background: url(../img/playButtonHover.png);
}
```

and give it a given size, like so:

```
div.videoPreviewImg i {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-left: -24px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  width:48px;
  height:48px;
}
```

and last but not least set a width on the video preview rather than a max-width:

```
div.videoPreviewImg img {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after
> pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted
> using the content property are anonymous replaced elements. - MDN

[Content CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)
Basically you were miss using the content property, and hence getting an unpredictable result. Check out the above link for more info

Comment: Thanks, apaul. Unfortunately, no dice :(  I implemented your changes and it stopped working in Chrome too. That seemed to be because of the change from content to background to insert the image. When I took that addition out, it went back to working fine in Chrome, but still no luck in Firefox. Thank you for your thorough reply though! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @BrandonMcPeak You just need to add width and height to `div.videoPreviewImg i` you have width twice and no height. it will work in chrome just checked

Comment: @BrandonMcPeak did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have figured out the issue. Thank you all a ton for your input. When I included the buttons as an image instead of an icon, it showed in Firefox. I didn't want to do this since the buttons are not content, but since it's the only fix that has worked, I'm probably going to stick with it. Thanks again!